# Rowdata not visible in telerik radGrid view

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, telerik-grid

I have a RasGridView with 2 rows of data fetched from SQL to be displayed in the grid.

```
 If oSQL.IsConnected Then
            Try
                ds = oSQL.GetDataSet("Select * from calc_umns order by calc_id", CommandType.Text)

                If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    ds.Tables(0).TableName = "getSavedCalc"

                    RadGridView1.MasterGridViewTemplate.AutoGenerateColumns = False
                    RadGridView1.DataSource = ds
                    RadGridView1.DataMember = "getSavedCalc"
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End If
```

But the grid shows two rows with no data in it. could anyone guide where I am going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The FieldName property should be SET unique name and field value doesn't correspond to the SQL column names only FieldName property does.